# Using Openweather JSON API,how to fetch the temperature?

Tags: jquery, json, openweathermap

Using Openweather JSON API by passing Latitude, Longitude , I am fetching the data. I need to fetch current temperature in Fahrenheit

Based on the example api provided on Openweather, i am reading the data from the field : deg

Example :

"wind":{"speed":5.1,"deg":310}

degree : 310.

Value which i am reading is incorrect. What exact value, i need to read for degree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Code Example

Weather in my neighborhood is 35 degrees response is 32 degrees.

```js
let API_KEY = 'e0a3dfaead51bbda58049371909fe21f';

function getWeather(latitude, longtitude) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather',
    data: {
      lat: latitude,
      lon: longtitude,
      units: 'imperial',
      APPID: API_KEY
    },
    success: data => {
       console.log(data["main"]["temp"] + " F");
    }
  })
}

getWeather(40.863372, -74.113181);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## explanation

Set the units to imperial so that the default temp will be returned in Farenheight `units=imperial` and the current temperature is located under the the `main.temp`

The docs say this is a sample response:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 145.77,
    "lat": -16.92
  },
  "weather": [{
    "id": 803,
    "main": "Clouds",
    "description": "broken clouds",
    "icon": "04n"
  }],
  "base": "cmc stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 293.25,
    "pressure": 1019,
    "humidity": 83,
    "temp_min": 289.82,
    "temp_max": 295.37
  },
  "wind": {
    "speed": 5.1,
    "deg": 150
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 75
  },
  "rain": {
    "3h": 3
  },
  "dt": 1435658272,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 8166,
    "message": 0.0166,
    "country": "AU",
    "sunrise": 1435610796,
    "sunset": 1435650870
  },
  "id": 2172797,
  "name": "Cairns",
  "cod": 200
}
```

The current weather is found in `main` :

```
"main": {
  "temp": 306.15, //current temperature
  "pressure": 1013,
  "humidity": 44,
  "temp_min": 306, //min current temperature in the city
  "temp_max": 306 //max current temperature in the city
},
```

To set the units of temp you use the `units=` parameter:

`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=London&units=imperial`

More info from their [docs](https://openweathermap.org/current#geo)

And all the parameters you could use [here](http://openweathermap.org/weather-data)

Comment: Thanks. I am passing the same. Imperial and picking the Temperature from main.  306.45 F or 293.25 F are not correct temperature. Temperature usually comes on 2 digits ... the location which i am testing .. has temperature of around 35 F

Comment: maybe you're looking for `units=metric` in Celcius. Which location are you testing?? @goofyui

Comment: I live in New Jersey.. if you try any city name in openweather.org, you can see the weather around 32.8 F

Comment: @goofyui I live in Jersey too! I just tested it out using imperial and I get accurate results.

Comment: Portorreal, I am sorry. I haven't added the "  &units=imperial " in the link. that's why i was getting invalid data.  Now its working fine. Thanks for your help